# Which Fully Homomorphic Encryption schemes are fastest?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I want to know which one Fully homomorphic encryption schemes are the best in terms of time to encrypt & decrypt or compare between them ?(Preferred valid link)

Comment: [OT] There aren't any FHE schemes currently in practical use owing to their high inefficiency, if I don't err.

Comment: Whether something is efficient or inefficient always depends on your point of view. For some applications 1 ms may be slow, for others 10 seconds may be more than fast enough.

Comment: I want compare schemes in Time or performance between them

Comment: Encrypt and decrypt are usually not the operations we are worried about when it comes to performance with FHE. We are more worried about performance when computing on the ciphertexts.

Comment: Extending on mikeazo's comment: Which scheme is best strongly depends on your application. Do you really need fully homomorphic or is somewhat homomorphic enough? Over which field do you represent your problem? For a comparison of some systems take a look at [Which Ring Based Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption Scheme is Best?](http://ia.cr/2015/889), but be aware that it was written before http://ia.cr/2016/127 and http://ia.cr/2016/717 .

Answer (score 4):

Encryption and decryption are usually the least problematic operations, in terms of performance, in FHE schemes.

The main software library I know for FHE is [HElib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib), which is regularly maintained and been around for a while now. 
There are several different papers about various benchmarks of HElib. 
The most recent one I could find was [HEtest: A Homomorphic Encryption Testing Framework](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/416.pdf). In Section 6.7 you find their encryption and decryption benchmarks. They state 33 ms for encryption and *up to* 5 seconds for decryption.

Very recently, there appeared a new library [$\Lambda \circ \lambda$](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lol.pdf) (code can be found [here](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lol.pdf)).
In Section E.2.2 they provide some performance results for a Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption (SHE) scheme, which allow you to evaluate circuits of a fixed depth.
If I read the table (Figure 10) correct, then their encryption needs around 371 ms and their decryption 2.3 ms.

Comment: thanks for your answer . but in HElib and paper that you offer doesn't compare and survey FHE schemes in term of Performance (even time Enc & Dec) however this title is new for me thanks.
sorry for my bad language :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I do not know of any thorough performance comparison of all possible FHE schemes, but my point was that if you are just looking for the fastest one, then I'd probably stick with something the experts in this field decided to implement.